# PM2 logrotation different configuration for different apps running

Tags: node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I was wondering if there is a way to set different logrotation configs for different pm2 apps running. Like I am running 4 different node applications using pm2 but all of them are taking the same logrotation configs I set using pm2-logrotate module.

Is there a way I can define different log rotation configs for each applications running?